# Random bouncing balls

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that contains 100 random balls with only red, green or blue colors. I can only use [`edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw`](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) and `java.util.Random` libraries. Also I have to store the ball objects in an array.

I wrote this code but when I run it, I only see one ball. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Ball {
    private static double x;
    private static double y;
    private static double vx;
    private static double vy;
    private static double r;
    private static Color c;
    private static int number;
    private static Ball[] balls;
    private static Color[] ballColors;
    
    public Ball(double x, double y, double vx, double vy, double r, Color c) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vx = vx;
        this.vy = vy;
        this.r = r;
        this.c= c;
    }
    
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("vx: "+vx+" ve vy: "+vy);
    }
    
    public static void setImage() {
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
    }
    
    public void move() {
        /*
        if(Math.abs(x + vx) > (1.0 - r)) {
            vx = -vx;
        }
        
        if(Math.abs(y + vy) > (1.0 - r)) {
            vy = -vy;
        }
        */
        
        x = x + vx;
        y = y + vy;
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);
        StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, r);  
        StdDraw.setPenColor(c);
    }
    
    public static double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    
    public double getVy() {
        return vy;
    }
    
    public static double getVx() {
        return vx;
    }
    
    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }
    
    public void setX(double newX) {
        x = newX;
    }
    
    public void setY(double newY) {
        y = newY;
    }
    
    public void setVx(double newVx) {
        vx = newVx;
    }
    
    public void setVy(double newVy) {
        vy = newVy;
    }
    
    public void setR(double newR) {
        r = newR;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ball.setImage();
        
        number = 100; //number of balls
        balls = new Ball[number];
        ballColors = new Color[] {StdDraw.GREEN, StdDraw.RED, StdDraw.BLUE};
        
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            do {
                x = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));
            do {
                y = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));
            
            vx = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            vy = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            r = random.nextDouble() * 0.08 + 0.02; 
            c = ballColors[(random.nextInt(3))];
            balls[i] = new Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, c);
        }
       
        while(true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                balls[i].draw();
                balls[i].move();

                // check if ball has hit a wall and change direction
                if(Math.abs(balls[i].getX() + balls[i].getVx()) > (1.0 - r)) {
                    balls[i].setVx(-balls[i].getVx());
                }
                
                if(Math.abs(balls[i].getY() + balls[i].getVy()) > (1.0 - r)) {
                    balls[i].setVy(-balls[i].getVy());
                }

                //balls[i].test();
                StdDraw.show();
                StdDraw.pause(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Way too much improper use of the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Ishan This isn't Swing code. It's using [StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html). Calling `StdDraw.show()` and `StdDraw.pause()` in a loop is the recommended way to do double-buffered animation.

Comment: You call `.clear()` in the `draw()` method of each individual ball. In addition to anything else that may be wrong, that alone would also show only the last ball to be drawn. You should call `clear()` *before drawing any balls* and never again.

Comment: @JoachimSauer when I did what you said, it creates so many same balls in the same time so it looks like a moving snake. When I add ```clear()``` method into the while loop, same thing happens again. And when I add it into the for loop, it only creates one ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated response

Instead of pulling in `StdDraw` from Maven (as I did below), I just copy-pasted the [source code](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java) of the original class into my own local copy. This version comes with the `enableDoubleBuffering` and `pause` methods.

Your main issue is calling `show()` and `pause(20)` each time your render `Ball` to the canvas. Loop over all the balls and update their positions. After you have updated all the positions (and accounted for collisions), you can draw them. Once you draw them, you can call `show()`.

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;

public class App {
    private static final Color[] BALL_COLORS;

    private static int number;
    private static Ball[] balls;

    static {
        BALL_COLORS = new Color[]{StdDraw.GREEN, StdDraw.RED, StdDraw.BLUE};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();

        while (true) {
            loop();
        }
    }

    public static void setImage() {
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, 1.0);
    }

    private static void initialize() {
        setImage();

        double x, y, vx, vy, r;
        Color c;

        number = 100;
        balls = new Ball[number];

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            vx = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            vy = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            r = random.nextDouble() * 0.08 + 0.02;
            c = BALL_COLORS[(random.nextInt(3))];

            do {
                x = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));
            do {
                y = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));

            balls[i] = new Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, c);
        }
    }

    private static void loop() {
        StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);

        // Update positions
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            Ball ball = balls[i];

            ball.move();

            // check if ball has hit a wall and change direction
            if (Math.abs(ball.getX() + ball.getVx()) > (1.0 - ball.getR())) {
                ball.setVx(-ball.getVx());
            }

            if (Math.abs(ball.getY() + ball.getVy()) > (1.0 - ball.getR())) {
                ball.setVy(-ball.getVy());
            }
        }

        // Render
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            balls[i].draw();
        }

        // Update canvas
        StdDraw.show();
        StdDraw.pause(20);
    }

    public static class Ball {
        private double x, y;
        private double vx, vy;
        private double r;
        private Color c;

        public Ball(double x, double y, double vx, double vy, double r, Color c) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.vy = vy;
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("vx: " + vx + " ve vy: " + vy);
        }

        public void move() {
            x += vx;
            y += vy;
        }

        public void draw() {
            StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, r);
            StdDraw.setPenColor(c);
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public double getVy() {
            return vy;
        }

        public double getVx() {
            return vx;
        }

        public double getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public void setX(double newX) {
            x = newX;
        }

        public void setY(double newY) {
            y = newY;
        }

        public void setVx(double newVx) {
            vx = newVx;
        }

        public void setVy(double newVy) {
            vy = newVy;
        }

        public void setR(double newR) {
            r = newR;
        }
    }
}
```

### Original response

You should restructure the program. The `Ball` class should not be responsible for drawing all the balls.

Move this to its own class.

```java
package org.example;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;

public class App {
    private static final Color[] BALL_COLORS;

    private static int number;
    private static Ball[] balls;

    static {
        BALL_COLORS = new Color[]{StdDraw.GREEN, StdDraw.RED, StdDraw.BLUE};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialize();

        while (true) {
            loop();
        }
    }

    public static void setImage() {
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500, 500);
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, 1.0);
    }

    private static void initialize() {
        setImage();

        double x, y, vx, vy, r;
        Color c;

        number = 100;
        balls = new Ball[number];

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            vx = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            vy = random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
            r = random.nextDouble() * 0.08 + 0.02;
            c = BALL_COLORS[(random.nextInt(3))];

            do {
                x = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));
            do {
                y = random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            } while (Math.abs(x) > (1 - r));

            balls[i] = new Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r, c);
        }
    }

    private static void loop() {
        StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            Ball ball = balls[i];

            ball.draw();
            ball.move();

            // check if ball has hit a wall and change direction
            if (Math.abs(ball.getX() + ball.getVx()) > (1.0 - ball.getR())) {
                ball.setVx(-ball.getVx());
            }

            if (Math.abs(ball.getY() + ball.getVy()) > (1.0 - ball.getR())) {
                ball.setVy(-ball.getVy());
            }

            //balls[i].test();
        }

        StdDraw.show();
        StdDraw.pause(20); // The pause method is undefined in version 1.0.1
    }

    public static class Ball {
        private double x, y;
        private double vx, vy;
        private double r;
        private Color c;

        public Ball(double x, double y, double vx, double vy, double r, Color c) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.vx = vx;
            this.vy = vy;
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void test() {
            System.out.println("vx: " + vx + " ve vy: " + vy);
        }

        public void move() {
            x += vx;
            y += vy;
        }

        public void draw() {
            StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, r);
            StdDraw.setPenColor(c);
        }

        public double getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public double getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public double getVy() {
            return vy;
        }

        public double getVx() {
            return vx;
        }

        public double getR() {
            return r;
        }

        public void setX(double newX) {
            x = newX;
        }

        public void setY(double newY) {
            y = newY;
        }

        public void setVx(double newVx) {
            vx = newVx;
        }

        public void setVy(double newVy) {
            vy = newVy;
        }

        public void setR(double newR) {
            r = newR;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should make this a Maven project, if you haven't already. Here is the required dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.princeton-java-introduction</groupId>
    <artifactId>stdlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Boilerplate and Lombok

If you use Lombok, you can reduce your `Ball` class to simply:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Ball {
    private double x, y;
    private double vx, vy;
    private double r;
    private Color c;

    public void move() {
        x += vx;
        y += vy;
    }

    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, r);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(c);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("vx: " + vx + " ve vy: " + vy);
    }
}
```

Here is the Maven dependency for Lombok:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.30</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**Note:** I noticed that both the `1.0.0` and `1.0.1` dependencies lack a `StdDraw::pause(int)` method...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.princeton-java-introduction</groupId>
    <artifactId>introcs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I apply what you said, it only creates 100 different balls. They are not moving, even I add the ```x += x + vx``` codes.

Comment: @refik I updated my response. See the new code at the beginning.

Comment: It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @refik I called `StdDraw.show()` and `StdDraw.pause(20)` outside of the `for`-loop.

Comment: If this helped you, feel free to accept this.

Answer (score 4):

The only fields in your "Ball" class that should be `static` are "number", "balls", and "ballColors" as they are shared across all instances. All other fields need the `static` REMOVED so that each instance gets its own copy that is independent of the other instances.

So the fields would be:

```
public class Ball {

    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double vx;
    private double vy;
    private double r;
    private Color c;
    private static int number;
    private static Ball[] balls;
    private static Color[] ballColors;

    // ... other existing code ...

}
```

Comment: I know I'm not a smooth code writer yet, but is that the cause of the problem I'm facing? Because it still doesn't work.

Comment: That was at least one problem. By making those fields static, they were shared across all instances. With them static, if you change the values in one instance, then all  instances would also only see those values. This would effectively give you just ONE BALL.

Comment: You're right. I completely forgot object oriented programming's purpose. I just was so focused the wirte and run this code the way that I want. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make all balls visible, just move `StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);` out of `box.draw()` to the `while` loop.

Additionnaly you should split `move()` and `draw()` for all balls at once

```java
public class App {

    private static final int XMIN = -1;
    private static final int XMAX = 1;
    private static final int YMIN = -1;
    private static final int YMAX = 1;

    private final Color[] colors = { StdDraw.GREEN, StdDraw.RED, StdDraw.BLUE };
    private final Ball[] balls;

    public App(int totalBalls) {
        balls = new Ball[totalBalls];
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int totalBalls = 100;
        int canvasWidth = 500;
        int canvasHeight = 500;

        App app = new App(totalBalls);
        app.init(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        while (true) {
            app.loop();
        }
    }

    private void init(int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight) {
        setImage(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
            double radius = random.nextDouble() * 0.08 + 0.02;
            Color color = colors[random.nextInt(3)];

            balls[i] = new Ball(radius, color);
            balls[i].x = getCoordinate(random, XMIN, XMAX, radius);
            balls[i].y = getCoordinate(random, YMIN, YMAX, radius);
            balls[i].vx = getSpeed(random);
            balls[i].vy = getSpeed(random);
        }
    }

    private static double getCoordinate(Random random,
                                        double min, double max,
                                        double radius) {
        min += radius;
        max -= radius;
        return (random.nextDouble() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    private static double getSpeed(Random random) {
        return random.nextDouble() * 0.04 - 0.02;
    }

    private static void setImage(int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight) {
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        StdDraw.setXscale(XMIN, XMAX);
        StdDraw.setYscale(YMIN, YMAX);
    }

    private void loop() {
        StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.BOOK_LIGHT_BLUE);

        moveBalls();
        drawBalls();

        StdDraw.show();
        StdDraw.pause(20);
    }

    private void moveBalls() {
        for (Ball ball : balls) {
            ball.move();

            hitTheWallX(ball);
            hitTheWallY(ball);
        }
    }

    private void drawBalls() {
        for (Ball ball : balls)
            ball.draw();
    }

    private static void hitTheWallX(Ball ball) {
        if (ball.x - ball.radius <= XMIN || ball.x + ball.radius >= XMAX)
            ball.vx = -ball.vx;
    }

    private static void hitTheWallY(Ball ball) {
        if (ball.y - ball.radius <= YMIN || ball.y + ball.radius >= YMAX)
            ball.vy = -ball.vy;
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    private static class Ball {

        private final double radius;
        private final Color color;

        private double x;
        private double y;
        private double vx;
        private double vy;

        public void move() {
            x += vx;
            y += vy;
        }

        public void draw() {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
            StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, radius);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: when I do this it creates a bunch of same balls one after the other and draws a moving snake, not hundred different balls. The ```clear()``` method only works properly in for loop, I don't understand why.